# Which Pokémon have a further evolution that isn't yet available?

Tags: pokemon-go

My motivation behind this question is to know which candy I should be collecting to be able to evolve Pokémon once their evolutions become available.

Comment: Since a large number of these Pokémon new/different evolution methods, you'll probably need more than just candies to evolve them, so while saving up the candies is a good idea, it won't mean you'll be able to evolve all of these as soon as they're released, necessarily.

Comment: I feel this is far too broad; there are, what? 700+ Pokémon now? And we're supposed to compile a list that shows which will be able to evolve in the future? That's what a reference site is for, not Arqade.

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic. It's reasonable to assume that the trend of adding new Pokemon to the game will continue and it is not that the Pokemon themselves are a secret as their existence is not based on this game. Any serious player has probably wondered of this and this question and answer would be of great assistance. According to my understanding this closing reason is meant for questions asking for example about unknown future features that only someone with inside information could know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of right now, there are quite a few Pokémon that will have evolutions available once the fourth generation is released. These are:

- Roselia -> Roserade
- Aipom -> Ambipom
- Misdreavus -> Mismagius
- Murkrow -> Honchkrow
- Sneasel -> Weavile
- Magneton -> Magnezone
- Lickitung -> Lickilicky
- Rhydon -> Rhyperior
- Tangela -> Tangrowth
- Electabuzz -> Electivire
- Magmar -> Magmortar
- Togetic -> Togekiss
- Yanma -> Yanmega
- Eevee -> Leafeon **AND** Glaceon
- Gligar -> Gliscor
- Piloswine -> Mamoswine
- Porygon2 -> Porygon-Z
- Kirlia -> Gallade
- Nosepass -> Probopass
- Dusclops -> Dusknoir
- Snorunt -> Froslass

After that, there is one additional evolution added to an existing Pokémon in Gen VI:

- Eevee -> Sylveon

---

Note that I've only listed Pokémon that will have their evolution chains extended or branched with later generations. I have not included Pokémon that have pre-evolutions added or Pokémon that may get alternate/Alolan forms.

Comment: Bulbapedia maintains a list of [**Pokemon with cross-generational evolutions**](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_with_cross-generational_evolutions). Assuming Pokemon Go continues to play 'catch up' with later Pokemon generations, this would be a good list to keep an eye on :)